# How to change image source using state variable with React.js

Tags: reactjs

I have an image component with the following html:

```
<img src={this.state.img_path} onClick={this.getNew} alt={this.state.alt} width={150} />
```

Initially I set the image to Blank which I import from an image:

import Blank from './images/blank.jpg';

then I use `Blank` to initialize my state variable.

When the image is clicked, `getNew` is called, where I set the state variable `img_path` to a relative image path:

```
this.setState({img_path: item.ImgPath, alt: item.alt});
```

The function `getNew` gets called without an issue and executes without an error but the image does not get displayed, just an icon and `alt` value. How do i do dynamic image source switch in React?

Update:

here is my class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import Blank from './images/blank.jpg';



class myImg extends Component {


    constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {

        img_path: Blank,

        alt: 'blank',   
    };


    this.getNew = this.getNew.bind(this);
}



getNew() {

    const items = [{ItemName: 'test1', ItemImg: './images/test1.jpg'}, {ItemName: 'test2', ItemImg: './images/test2.jpg'} ];

    var item = items[math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)]; 
    this.setState({ img_path: item.ItemImg,
            alt: item.ItemName });
  }

 render() {
     return (<div>
            <img src={this.state.img_path} onClick={this.getNew} alt={this.state.alt} width={150} />

        </div>);

}

}

export default myImg;
```

Comment: if you console.log() your img_path where you are returning the image component are you getting the new path correctly?

Comment: can you share a working snippet

Comment: @Rodius, yes, I do

Comment: @stack26, just added the whole class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the fix. I used `require`. At first it did not work but then I wrapped the image path state variable in `${}`. Basically I changed

```
<img src={this.state.img_path} onClick={this.getNew} alt={this.state.alt} width={150} />
```

to

```
<img src={require(`${this.state.img_path}`)} onClick={this.getNew} alt={this.state.alt} width={150} />
```

that got the image to be displayed